# Access ng-model inside jQuery control

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created an AngularJS directive using the bootstrap-datepicker which is based on jQuery and I want some stuff based on the `ng-model` which I'm sending to the directive. The problem is that on the datepicker init click events I don't have access to anything angular related. There is no `scope`, no `ngModel` nothing. All of these are undefined. Now, I might be missing something obvious, but I don't know what this is. Here is the code for the directive:

```
.directive('jqCalendar', function () {
  return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      require: 'ngModel',
      template: '<div></div>',
      replace: true,
      scope:{
          ngModel: '='
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
          var ngModel = scope.ngModel;
          element.datepicker({
              multidate: true,
              beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                  var today = new Date();
                  var angularModel = ngModel; //ngModel is always undefined in here, why?!
                  if (date < today) return false;
              },
              format: 'dd MM yyyy',
              weekStart: 1
          })
          .on('changeDate', function (e) {
              //make server call for selected/deselected date
              alert('asd');
          });
      }
   }
})
```

Outside the `element.datepicker({...})` I can see the value of my model, but once inside the said control, I cannot access anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Your problem *may* be initialization order. Perhaps you should watch the `ngModelCtrl.$viewValue`. **Better yet** try to implement a custom control with `ngModel` as shown in the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) (under "Custom Control Example - override `$render()` and use `$setViewValue`). If you could provide your case in a complete fiddle, maybe we could help more.

Comment: I'll give that a try and see how it goes. Thanks.